# Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account

Tags: rust, anchor, smartcontracts, solana

I simply tried transferring token from account A (*vault_account*) to account B (*receiver_account*) using both traditional method and anchor method. In both of the methods i used *receiver_account* as signer. But the anchor method is throwing `Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Cross-program invocation with unauthorized signer or writable account`. This error was solved if i use *vault_account* as signer. Can anyone explain why is this happening because
As far as i know both of these method does the same thing under the hood.

**Traditional method**:

```
let (_account_address, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
            &[&sender_account.key.to_bytes()], 
            program_id
        );

        let pda_signer_seeds: &[&[_]] = &[&sender_account.key.to_bytes(), &[bump]];
        
        //transfering token to receiver_associated_info
        invoke_signed(
            &spl_token::instruction::transfer(
                token_program_info.key,
                vault_associated_info.key,
                receiver_associated_info.key,
                vault.key,
                &[vault.key],
                amount,
            )?,
            &[
                token_program_info.clone(),
                vault_associated_info.clone(),
                receiver_associated_info.clone(),
                vault.clone(),
                system_program.clone()
            ],&[&pda_signer_seeds],
        )?;
```

**Anchor method:**

```
 let (_account_address, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
            &[&ctx.accounts.sender_account.key.to_bytes()], 
            ctx.program_id
        );

        let pda_signer_seeds: &[&[&[_]]] = &[&[&ctx.accounts.vault.key.to_bytes(), &[bump]]];
        
        let transfer_ix = Token_Transfer{
            from: ctx.accounts.vault_associated_info.to_account_info(),
            to: ctx.accounts.receiver_associated_info.to_account_info(),
            authority: ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info()
        };

        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            transfer_ix,
            pda_signer_seeds,
        );
        
        token_transfer(cpi_ctx, amount)?;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the traditional method, you need to pass in the accounts in the correct order, and specify the arguments correctly:

```
        invoke_signed(
            &spl_token::instruction::transfer(
                token_program_info.key,
                vault_associated_info.key,
                receiver_associated_info.key,
                vault.key,
                &[],
                amount,
            )?,
            [
                vault_associated_info.clone(),
                receiver_associated_info.clone(),
                vault.clone(),
                token_program_info.clone()
            ],&[&pda_signer_seeds],
        )?;
```

This is assuming that `vault.key == _account_address` derived earlier, otherwise you may get an error.

For Anchor, you'll need to specify the correct program that you're invoking:

```
        let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(
            ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
            transfer_ix,
            pda_signer_seeds,
        );
```

Separate note: in the case of an SPL token transfer, you don't need the receiver to sign, only the authority of the sender account.